# SQL Server Stored Procedure reports successful execution but query(s) within it do not execute

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-agent

We use a suite of stored procedures to fulfill one of our ETL pipelines, which relies on linked servers using a push strategy. The stored procedures are run one-per-step in a SQL Server Agent job. The servers exist in the same VLAN and have a 10GBPS connection.

> We realize a pull strategy is ideal, and are working to apply this approach across our workloads.

The ETL agent is typically successful and has been a working solution for quite some time. Intermittently one or more of the stored procedures will report a successful execution but in truth it does not execute. I have verified this scenario on numerous occassions.

> The agent history indicates no errors have occurred and our custom error table (populated by our error handler stored procedure) shows no errors for the migration. All stored procedures have been verified to be working correctly and are free of logic bugs, as evidenced by the fact that in most cases data is `INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE`(ed) successfully.

Manually executing the failed stored procedure does not produce different results. The confusing part about the situation is that if a query contained within the stored procedure is extracted and executed manually, it succeeds in `INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE`(ing) the data.

My best guess is that this is perhaps being caused by a cached query plan. Though, I'm entirely unsure.

---

Our stored procedures for this use case always contain a try/catch to handle and log any errors. In structure, they usually resemble something like the following:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.some_etl_proc
AS
  BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    BEGIN TRY

      ---------
      -- delete
      ---------
      DELETE  at
      FROM    LINKED_SERVER.ANOTHER_DB.dbo.another_table AS at
              LEFT JOIN SOME_DB.dbo.some_table AS st 
                ON st.some_table_id = at.some_table_id
      WHERE   st.some_table_id IS NULL;

      ---------
      -- update
      ---------
      UPDATE  at
      SET     col_1 = st.col_1
            , col_2 = st.col_2
      FROM    LINKED_SERVER.ANOTHER_DB.dbo.another_table AS at
              JOIN SOME_DB.dbo.some_table AS st 
                ON st.some_table_id = at.some_table_id;

      ---------
      -- insert 
      ---------
      INSERT INTO LINKED_SERVER.ANOTHER_DB.dbo.another_table (col_1, col_2)
      SELECT  st.col_1
            , st.col_2
      FROM    SOME_DB.dbo.some_table AS st              
              LEFT JOIN LINKED_SERVER.ANOTHER_DB.dbo.another_table AS at
                ON at.some_table_id = st.some_table_id
      WHERE   at.some_table_id IS NULL;
      
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
      IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRAN;

      -- we log the error here using a custom sproc
      EXEC dbo.error_handler

      RETURN 55555;
    END CATCH;
  END;
```

---

Our error handler looks like:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.error_handler
AS
  DECLARE @errmsg NVARCHAR(2048)
        , @severity TINYINT
        , @state TINYINT
        , @errno INT
        , @proc sysname
        , @lineno INT;

  SELECT  @errmsg = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        , @severity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
        , @state = ERROR_STATE()
        , @errno = ERROR_NUMBER()
        , @proc = ERROR_PROCEDURE()
        , @lineno = ERROR_LINE();

  IF @errmsg NOT LIKE '***%'
    BEGIN
      SELECT  @errmsg = N'*** ' + COALESCE(QUOTENAME(@proc), '<dynamic SQL>') + N', Line ' + LTRIM(STR(@lineno)) + N'. Errno ' + LTRIM(STR(@errno)) + N': ' + @errmsg;
    END;

  INSERT INTO dbo.db_error 
  SELECT  GETDATE()
        , SYSTEM_USER
        , @errno
        , @severity
        , @state
        , @lineno
        , @errmsg
        , @proc;

  RAISERROR('%s', @severity, @state, @errmsg);
```

Comment: Maybe the table on the linked server is empty (or is missing the rows you expect) when the job runs. And later when you try to run the update statements to reproduce the issue, the table is having the expected data.

Comment: Are you checking your log or the Agent job history to determine whether there are errors? You might want to try logging the start of each SP _before_ the `try` and the successful completion, if any.

Comment: @Wouter appreciate the feedback but that isn't the case here.

Comment: @HABO the logs show only successful executions. Not really sure how logging before the `TRY` helps here? The sprocs have all run successfully for quite some time and this issue is intermittent.

Comment: Does "log the error" also mean your code eats the error and the caller never receives the error message at all (except via the return value of 5555)? IOW - does your catch not rethrow the error?

Comment: @SMor great question! It does not swallow it, and uses `RAISEERROR(...)`. I've updated the question with the code.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the right code? The entirety of your error_handler proc is a declare statement.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yup the code is accurate, you may need to scroll to see the rest of the sproc.